# Can I create quiz GUI with Django-Forms?

Tags: django-forms

I'm new to django, and I'm working on a quiz project. The idea is to create something similar to this (http://www.stylemint.com/quiz). Basically, there will be a question on each page and the user clicks on an image with the answer. I was planning on using a django form with a radio select input type, however, I'd like the image to act as the radio button (ie, be clickable) and also a click on the image will take you to the next question (instead of having to click submit after each). Is this possible with django, or do I need java?

Answer (score 0):

it's perfectly possible - if you just want a series of images, and clicking on them to take you to the next question you might achieve that by:

1. Having multiple input fields of type "image" which all submit the form. If you go down that route you'll have to template the forms out yourself or make your own widget.
2. Using javascript to replace radio buttons with images dynamically. If you do that, it'd be a good idea to make it fall back to a straight list selection for people who don't have javascript.
3. Ignoring forms altogether and just using a view with a parameter of what the choice is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's completely possible. My suggestion is if you want to save the result in the db use model and model form in django. So, my next suggestion is you can customize model field for combine radio button functionality and image together. But actually you must programming and use a little jquery and javascript to do it.

You may want to see:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/